# Excel: Count specific text strings from different cells within text of one cell

Tags: excel

If in cell A1 I have three names and in cell range B1:E1 I have a list of names, how can I count how many of the names in B1:E1 appear in cell A1?

For example:

A1: Peter Paul Laura
B1: Peter
C1: James
D1: Laura
E1: Paul

The formula should return 3, since 3/4 names on the list are in cell A1. 
If possible, the formula should be for an infinite amount of names that could occur in cell A1.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Kind regards,
Raoul

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach if:

- Names only appear once
- Names are not a subset of each other (e.g. code below will count Jonathon if "Jon" is listed).  You could add a space to the end of the names in B1:end to prevent this.

It will skip blank cells so that you can make it look at as many cells as you want.  This is an **array formula** that needs to be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.  I extended it through `G1` even though data stops in `E1` to show the blank handling.

```
=COUNT(IF(ISBLANK(B1:G1),FALSE,  FIND(B1:G1,A1)))
```

This code works by counting the number of times that `FIND` returns a number.  `COUNT` will skip errors which is what is returned if nothing is found.  `FIND` works by searching for one string inside another one.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your help, this approach works!!! If only I'd asked sooner...